# duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 framework included twice

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

This is not the regular duplicate symbols error. I am using AFNetworking library for networking with cocoa pods. I also using a third party framework that has been added to the target "Link Binary With Libraries" list in build phases section.

Unfortunately, This third party framework includes the AFNetworking that apparently is being used by it for networking.

Therefore, it makes sense that this error has been produced. Any idea how can this be solved?

**Edit:** Here it shows that kAFUploadStream3GSuggestedPacketSize symbol is defined in the afnetworking and in the OPPWAMobile framework. along with another 59 symbols.

> duplicate symbol _kAFUploadStream3GSuggestedPacketSize in:
>       /Users/khaled/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Saveto-fhceqhysbolbskawabayohjbtsra/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AFNetworking/libAFNetworking.a(AFURLRequestSerialization.o)
>       /Users/khaled/Development/iOS/Saveto/git@git.assembla.com:imena-develotpment-.29/OPPWAMobile.framework/OPPWAMobile
>   ld: 60 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**Podfile:**

```
platform :ios, '7.1'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'Saveto' do
    pod 'SWTableViewCell', '~> 0.3.7'
    pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 2'
    pod "AFNetworking"   , '~> 2'
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7'
    pod 'MMDrawerController', '~> 0.6.0'
    pod 'iRate'
    pod 'XLForm'
    pod "SwipeView", "~>1.3.2"
    pod "DAAlertController"
    pod "Mantle" , "~>2.0.4"
    pod 'pop', '~> 1.0'
    pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 1.12'
    pod 'SVProgressHUD'
    pod 'FXBlurView'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
end
```

Comment: Maybe try unlinking the third party framework usage of AFNetworking in Build Phases.

Comment: I tried to go deep in it. but its kind of closed component. I will try again.

Comment: I don't think that would work. cause how this framework gonna use the afnetworking if its not included in it.

Comment: Where does the third party framework link to AFNetworking? It should be able to pick up the Pods one.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gayfuqzdgf0d6fw/Hyperpay%201.3%20SDK.zip?dl=0 this is the sdk download link. can you please check it for me?

Comment: this is the integration guide: https://gate2play.docs.oppwa.com/tutorials/mobile-sdk/first-integration

Comment: I don't see any mention of AFNetworking in that framework.

Comment: I edited my question @l'L'l. can you check?

Comment: I think you'll need to modify your `Podfile`, can you post what you currently have?

Comment: I added my pod file

Comment: I think that I've spotted the problem, we can either chat about it or I'll just post an answer and you can hope it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144191/discussion-between-hasan83-and-lll).

Comment: @hasan can you please share latest OPPWAMobile.framework file. Because I am getting `NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"` this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about the Pod import of AFNetworking clashing with the 3rd party library which happens to contain the same symbols. There are are couple of ways to resolve it, the best and most sensible one would be to specify `use_frameworks!` in your Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
  target 'Saveto' do
    pod 'SWTableViewCell', '~> 0.3.7'
    pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 2'
    pod 'AFNetworking'   , '~> 2'
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7'
    pod 'MMDrawerController', '~> 0.6.0'
    pod 'iRate'
    pod 'XLForm'
    pod 'SwipeView', '~>1.3.2'
    pod 'DAAlertController'
    pod 'Mantle' , '~>2.0.4'
    pod 'pop', '~> 1.0'
    pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 1.12'
    pod 'SVProgressHUD'
    pod 'FXBlurView'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
end
```

I suppose you could also rename the symbols with a post_install method, although that might not resolve everything; there shouldn't be any issues after using the method above though.

Comment: Yes, ty that solved the problem but caused another problem with CocoaLumberjack that I am trying to solve. something with how to use the cocoa lumberjack the old way. which doesn't work with use_frameworks! !!!

Comment: This is actually an old project that has been handed to me. thats why the use_frameworks! was missing in the first place. ty for help.

Comment: now I solved the lumberjack problem. a new problem with the XLForm. omg